# How a nested default interface differs from a nested protected interface?

Tags: java, interface

What are the differences between nested default and nested protected interfaces in Java? Why nested protected interfaces are even allowed?

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    // not implementable outside of current package
    interface NestedDefaultInterface {

    }

    // not implementable outside of current package?
    protected interface NestedProtectedIface {

    }
}

// both interfaces can be implemented
class Best implements Test.NestedProtectedIface, Test.NestedDefaultInterface { 

}
```

MyClass.java

```
class AClass implements Test.NestedProtectedIface { //Error

}

class AnotherClass implements Test.NestedDefaultInterface { //Error

}

class OneMoreClass extends Test implements Test.NestedProtectedIface { //Error

}
```

Comment: Added an example where you can find the usage of nested interfaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the visual difference:

```
package com.one

public class Test {
    // not implementable outside of current package
    interface NestedDefaultInterface {

    }

    // implementable in child classes outside of package
    protected interface NestedProtectedIface {

    }
}
```

Outside of the package:

```
package com.two

class SubTest extends Test { 
    public void testProtected() {
        NestedProtectedIface npi = new NestedProtectedIface () {
           // implementation
        };
    }

    public void testDefault() {
        // Won't compile!
    //    NestedDefaultInterface ndi = new NestedDefaultInterface() {
    //    };
    }
}
```

The confusion here is about visibility.

When you extending a class you will get access to all `protected` parent properties from `this` reference.

For `default` access modifier it will not work outside of the package.

The most popular real-world example of nested interface is `Map.Entry<K,V>` of `java.util.Map`.

Each implementation of `Map` provides its own `Entry<K,V>` implementation. (`Node<K,V>` in `HashMap`, `Entry<K,V>` in `TreeMap` and etc.)